# Recibir y mandar información en un puerto serial. ¿Es posible?

Tags: c#, arduino

Estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto de conexión entre Arduino y Visual Studio. Consiste en mandar información de las lecturas de un sensor de humedad a Visual utilizando un puerto serial y desde dicha interfaz, decidir el umbral de humedad en el que un foco se debe encender.

Hasta ahora, he logrado visualizar la información del sensor en ListBoxes de C# en tiempo real y también la puedo insertar en un archivo .txt con acción de un botón.

Agregué un botón y una caja de texto en donde el usuario pueda escribir el umbral y lo mande a través del puerto.

```
    private void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string umbral;
        umbral = textBox1.Text;
        serialPort1.WriteLine(umbral);
    }
```

La verdad, no tengo idea si esto es posible, no estoy seguro como, posteriormente podría tratar esta información en el programa de Arduino y si puede interferir con lo que estoy leyendo de la tarjeta de la siguiente manera:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Omití las características del puerto para no atiborrar la pregunta
    {                 
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEventHandler);
        serialPort1.Open(); // Abrir puerto            
    } 

    private void DataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort1 = (SerialPort)sender;            
        string[] w = serialPort1.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(w[0])));
        Invoke(new Action(() => listBox2.Items.Add(w[1])));

    }
```

Tampoco se que tan viable sea que, en el programa de Arduino, agregue una variable extra a la cadena que envío al puerto, la cual sea leída permanentemente por este programa y que cada vez que el usuario la modifique en la interfaz esta cambie gracias a la partición de la cadena en un vector que hice con la función `Split`en `DataReceivedEventHandler`.

Esto es lo que tengo en Arduino:

```
void enviar_datos(float x, float y) {
     Serial.print(y);
     Serial.print(" ");
     Serial.println(x);
     //Agregar un espacio más
     //Agregar una nueva variable con un valor por default
}
```

Cualquier consejo y comentario es bienvenido. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, mi opinión respecto a añadir una variable para el umbral es un rotundo sí. 
Me explico, el proyecto en sí tiene como objetivo encender un foco (lo que se denomina un actuador) controlado por humedad (denominado sensor) y cuya variable de control en este caso será el umbral.

Dicho esto, el control sobre este actuador siempre va a depender de la variable de control lo que nos indica que siempre vamos a necesitar una variable de control con un valor asignado. Así pues, el usuario que utilice el proyecto que presentas, va a necesitar saber en que punto está el umbral, ya que en caso de necesidad este lo pueda ajustar (lo que se denomina calibración). Esto también nos indica que será necesario tener un valor por defecto cuando se encienda el Arduino (el default value que tú comentas).

En el Arduino vas necesitar también recibir dichos datos, siempre teniendo en cuenta que la función [Serial.Read](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/) devuelve el primer Byte de la trama. Es recomendable que busques ejemplos de como leer datos del puerto serie en Arduino. Una vez tratada la información que proviene del puerto serie, actualizar la variable de control umbral con dicho valor y re-enviarla por el puerto serie para informar al usuario que el cambio ha sido efectuado.

Sé que la respuesta es un tanto teórica, en caso de necesitar ayuda más técnica, no dudes en pedirla